# Best way to get second item of each list inside of a 2D list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2D list:

`items = [['a','b'],['c','d']]`

I would like to get a new list containing the last element of each nested list:

`new_list = ['b','d']`

I can do it like so:

```
new_list = []
for i in items:
   new_list.append(i[-1])
```

But this feels very clumsy for such a simple thing. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Your example is how I would accomplish this. Maybe a lambda function could do it better, but IMO it would be less clear.

Comment: The canonical way is a list comprehension: `new_list = [item[1] for item in items]`

Comment: use this script `new_list = [i[-1] for i in items]`

Comment: using lambda `list(map(lambda x:x[1], items))`

Answer (score 2):

If you have...

```
items = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd']
]
```

...you have a nested list that you can access this way:

```
>>> items[0]
['a', 'b']
>>> items[0][0]
```

---

To have the second element (the element with index `1`) of each sublist, I would suggest a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [sublist[1] for sublist in items]
```

If you want the last element (the element with index `-1`) of each sublist, you just have to change the index:

```
new_list = [sublist[-1] for sublist in items]
```

For the list you shown the two lines will give the same list, but when the sublists have more than two elements the two solution will give different results.

---

You can read more about list comprehension [`here`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) and [`here`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

From a readability perspective, I would probably combine iterable unpacking with list comprehension for something like -

```
new_list = [second for first, second, *rest in items]
```

The `*rest` is not really required in this case where the sublists have only 2 items, but helps generalize.

Comment: I didn't know this could work, +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
new_list = [i[-1] for i in items]
```

Comment: I would suggest to use index 1 instead of -1, since the question is asking for "the second item" and not for the last one, even thought the sublists are of lenght 2.

Comment: The question is actually unclear @FLAK-ZOSO -- in the body they say `the last character`.

Comment: Right, thank you to make me notice it, I'm editing my answer.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO you're right, I was looking at the question body and the sample code, which looked more like the OP wanted to get the last element. Probably the question title should be changed to match the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

using List comprehension:

```
items = [['a','b'],['c','d']]

new_list = [item[1] for item in items] # where 1 in item[1] is the index of last element or you can use -1

print(new_list) # ['b', 'd']
```